# Apple push: does it need an application at all?

Tags: iphone, push

Do we need to install an app to receive some push from a service ?
Is there a way to register an iphone somewhere (website / apple server) without having an app installed on the iphone to register to the push service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Push Notification Service is to be used with native iOS applications. Without an application APNS cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

you are saying you want to push a message to a particular iphone, but not have it related to any app? This is basically a text message, and you could do this from a server remotely using SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use Apple Push Notification Service, you will need an app.

But go have a try at notifio.com